# Is there a way to fix an encoding issue directly in my Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, character-encoding

I'm having an issue with my Wordpress install. Somehow all the content was inserted in the database with a wrong charset, but in the frontend is working smoothly.

As you can see here:
http://prntscr.com/8vifc3

I'm changing my host, but when I imported my site won'r render the encoding properly because of the way that the content was inserted.

There's a way so I can fix the encoding directly in my previous mysql before I export it?

Thanks

Comment: What is your collation for MySQL column in which your data is inserted? You can change character set from there. Maybe setting `utf8_general_ci` collation will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the issue by converting your strings to binary and then do charset conversion. The example below converts `UTF8` data to `CP1251`:

```
UPDATE table SET column=CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(column USING binary) USING utf8) USING cp1251) WHERE id=123;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)` function

in mysqli

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

or you can change the charset from phpmyadmin to `utf8_*`

Answer (score 0):

That's Mojibake

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

If you need to **fix the data** it takes a "2-step ALTER", something like

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```